# Apache Jena TDB with MySQL

Tags: mysql-workbench, sparql, apache-jena, tdb

I am working on the semantic web and use TDB for RDF storage.Is it possible that we could use TDB with MySQL Workbench and execute semantic queries against TDB data in Workbench ? I went through [Apache Jena TDB](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/)
tutorial but could not find anything regarding this. If possible could you tell if this is possible, please? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Apache Jena Fuseki. This provides a web UI to the RDF data and it uses TDB.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at [Jena SDB](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/sdb/).  TDB is a memory-mapped data store that represents triples directly.  To use third-party relational database, you need a connector and a way to save RDF in a relational model.  And that's basically what SDB does.

Comment: It is not really possible to use the MySQL workbench with SDB. You can not write SPARQL. SDB uses a custom schema which is not easy to write in SQL.

Comment: True.  One can use MySQL with SDB, not the Workbench.  Using a Jena ARQ front-end would be recommended to query the MySQL back-end.